# Win10 unable import p12 certificate

Tags: openssl

I generate the p12 certificate on linux.
And try to import this certificate to Windows10.then the error:「wrong password is input」is displayed.

Comment: Could the password be blank/empty?  When creating your p12 cert, did you specify `-keyex`?  Also, depending upon the certificate type, you may need to specify a `-CSP "Microsoft CSP name here"` option.  For a list of valid CSP names, check either `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Cryptography\Providers\Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider\Aliases` on your W10 PC, or [Microsoft CSPs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/microsoft-cryptographic-service-providers).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.